# Simple limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

So I just need a refresher on limits, it's pretty easy I think, I just forget what to do. The question is find $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{ \cos(3\pi/2 + h) - \cos (3\pi/2)}{h}$. Please just describe the steps, and I don't need dozens of replies, i've learnt this and just forget. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if anyone is willing to help with this problem, that would be much appreciated. What is the lim as x -> infinity for (x^2 - 4) / (2 + x - 4x^2).

Comment: Ans for ur comment ques is $\dfrac{-1}{4}$. BTW, Do u know L Hopital's Rule ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I may have known it and just didn't call it that.

Comment: Think about the definition of the derivative of the function $x\mapsto \cos \left(\frac{3\pi}2+x\right)$evaluated at $0$.

Comment: Read this  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule nd Now try to figure out yourself. Its easy now

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = \cos x$, and $a = \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$. The above limit is viewed as derivative of $f$ at $x = \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$. So $L = f'\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right) = -\sin(3\pi/2) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Putting $h=0$ gives indeterminite form $\dfrac{0}{0}$. Therefore, Applying L'Hôpital's rule, we get $$\lim_{ h \to 0 }\dfrac{\cos({\dfrac{3\pi}{2}+h)-\cos(\dfrac{3\pi}{2})}}{h}=\lim_{ h \to 0 }\dfrac{-sin(\dfrac{3\pi}{2})}{1}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Another way:**

$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{ \cos(3\pi/2 + h) - \cos (3\pi/2)}{h}
=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{-2\sin \frac{(3\pi/2+h+3\pi/2)}{2}\sin(\frac{3\pi/2+h-3\pi/2}{2})}{h}
=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{2\cos h\sin \frac h2}{h}
=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{2\frac h2}{h}=1
$

Comment: @Ethan,http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html